# Partial order of a finite set is an intersection of a finite number of linear orders of this set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, order-theory

I am trying to prove that every partial order of a finite set is an intersection of a finite number of linear orders of this set. Can this be proved using these observations:

1. a partial order has a linear extension
2. this partial order is an intersection of its linear extensions
3. there is a finite number of linear extensions

Or is there a simpler proof?

Comment: Yes, it can. This is how I’d prove it; I don’t see anything simpler, and this isn’t really very hard.

Comment: Related to the bullet point 3, the [paper](http://rutcor.rutgers.edu/pub/rrr/reports2002/35_2002.pdf) makes a claim that every partial order is an intersection of linear extensions but let the partial order to be infinite so the new question  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695566/partial-order-is-intersection-of-linear-extensions-also-if-poset-is-infinite to find out whether there is a mistake or misunderstanding in the paper.

Comment: Part 1 and 2 proved [here](http://jade-cheng.com/uh/coursework/math-475/homework-03.pdf).